# Transform json object to json array xslt 1.0

Tags: json, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new to the world of xslt and I need to transform json objects into "body" to json array, can you help me please? In the example code both "revista" and "periodicos" are objects, I need to transform them without "books" changing.

```
 {
    "Consultar": {
        "header": {
            "fechaHora": "20161017141835",
            "idioma": "ES"
        },
        "body": {
            "revistas": {
                "moneda": "USD",
                "valorPagar": "150.0",
                "nombre": "Revista1"
            },
            "libros": [{
                "nombre": "Libro1",
                "precio": "96.98"
            }, {
                "nombre": "Libro2",
                "precio": "25.62"
            }, {
                "nombre": "Libro3",
                "precio": "10"
            }],
            "periodicos": {
                "moneda": "USD",
                "valorPagar": "150.0",
                "nombre": "Periodico1"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: XSLT 3.0  has support for JSON, earlier versions not. Why do you need to use XSLT 1.0 for an input format that is not XML? Can't you use any language with a JSON parser?

Comment: The reason I use it is because before I make a soap-to-json transformation, but it transforms an array into a json object, and I need it to be a json array